# How do I get the snapshot length of a .pcap file using dpkt?

Tags: python, networking, pcap, dpkt

I am trying to get the snapshot length of a .pcap file.  I have gone to the man page for pcap and pcap_snapshot but have not been able to get the function to work.

I am running a VM Fedora20 and it is written in python

First I try to import the file that the man page says to include but I get a syntax error on the import and the pcap_snapshot()
I am new at python so I imagine its something simple but not sure what it is.  Any help is much appreciated!

```
import <pcap/pcap.h>
import dpkt

myPcap = open('mycapture.pcap')
myFile = dpkt.pcap.Reader(myPcap)

print "Snapshot length = ", myFile.pcap_snapshot()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't read the man page first unless you're writing code in C, C++, or Objective-C.

If you're not using a C-flavored language, you'll need to use a wrapper for libpcap, and should read the documentation for the wrapper first, as you won't be calling the C functions from libpcap, you'll be calling functions from the wrapper.  If you try to import a C-language header file, such as pcap/pcap.h, in Python, that will not work.  If you try to directly call a C-language function, such as `pcap_snapshot()`, that won't work, either.

Dpkt is not a wrapper; it is, instead, a library to parse packets and to read pcap files, with the code to read pcap files being independent of libpcap.  Therefore, it won't offer wrappers for libpcap APIs such as `pcap_snapshot()`.

Dpkt's documentation is, well, rather limited.  A quick look at its pcap.py module seems to suggest that

```
print "Snapshot length = ", myFile.snaplen
```

would work; give that a try.